# Replacing html entities with a text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please I want to replace html entities with a text like so: `<img src='my_image.jpg'>` so I ran this code:

`var image = $("#my_div").html($("#my_div").html().replace(/<img scr='(.*?)'>/g, "{{$1}}"));`

so when its outputted it show like this: `{{my_image.jpg}}` but when outputted this is what displays: `[object Object]`. Please I need help because I know am getting something wrong.

Comment: Wait... Can you show us in a snippet with a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to create the new value

```
<img id="myid" src="mypicture.jpg">

<script>
$('#myid').attr('src', function(i, origValue){
    return "{{" + origValue + "}}";
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change an img element's attribute (src in this case) like this :

Markup:

```
<img id="eximg" src="source.jpg">
```

Script:

```
$('#eximg').attr('src','anothersource.jpg');
```

Comment: I assumed he was looking for a "whatever the image filename is, add the curly brackets" solution. Your code is correct but will not solve the issue.